# Display three columns per row in MVC cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

What I have currently is the below which works fine but now it shows my records in a long list, what i want to do is show three(3) records per row. I tried putting a for loop over the  tags but it doesnt work it just displays duplicate of each record three(3) time.

```
   @foreach (var ClientItem in Model.Clients)
                    {
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="dataListItem" >
                                @Html.Hidden("ClientID", ClientItem.ClientID)
                                @Html.Label(ClientItem.ClientName)
                                <input type='checkbox' name="ClientItemCheckBox" id="ClientItemCheckBox" style="color: #428bca;" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                    }
```

please help I've ran out of ideas, I've also tried archive [that was asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142879/how-can-i-count-loops-in-mvc3-in-foreach)

Comment: use a counter to hold the index of your clients, and after the third item you add a new row `tr`

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap 3.x (default in new MVC projects) you can simply use CSS classes to control your column output and not even bother looping through at all.  Post a reply comment if you want me to expand an answer with an example.

Comment: Yes I'm using Bootstrap, please expand your answer. @AndrewCounts thank you. Unlike people who just downvote without explaining where I went wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using Bootstrap Responsive grids, it is not necessary to manually build a table and loop through the rows.  Bootstrap will automatically wrap columns for you.  Bootstrap works on a grid system using 12 columns, and if more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, [wrap onto a new line](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping).

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="dataListItem" class="col-md-4">
        @Html.Hidden("ClientID", ClientItem.ClientID)
        @Html.Label(ClientItem.ClientName)
        <input type='checkbox' name="ClientItemCheckBox" 
                    id="ClientItemCheckBox" style="color: #428bca;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

here is a sample on [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Rxm9oDFPWc)

Comment: WOW this was easy and straight forward, I will be taking this route from now on thanx man. Simplest and efficient answer I've ever  received here. It works by the way.

Comment: glad to help.  there are all kinds of advanced options you have with these grids, like handling overflow on different size devices.  The sample I posted using `col-md-4` will display one column on small (tablet) or extra small (phone) devices.  Resize your browser window to see the effect.

Comment: I will definitely look into them from now on...thanx once again.

Comment: Surely you should try to keep to only having a maximum of 12 columns defined per row? With this approach you could have 1000s of columns defined per row.

Answer (score 7):

Use `for` block and print `<tr>` or `</tr>` based on the value of `i`. If it's the first index (`i` equals 0) or it's the fourth, seventh, ... (3n+1)th index (`i % 3` equals 0), then print `<tr>` before `<td>`. If it's the last index (`i` equals `Model.Clients.Count - 1`) or it's the third, sixth, ... (3n)th index (`i % 3` equals 2), then print `</tr>` after `</td>`. The below code should give what you want.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Clients.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 0 || i % 3 == 0)
    {
        <tr>
    }
    <td>
        <div id="dataListItem" >
            @Html.Hidden("ClientID", Model.Clients[i].ClientID)
            @Html.Label(Model.Clients[i].ClientName)
            <input type='checkbox' name="ClientItemCheckBox" id="ClientItemCheckBox" style="color: #428bca;" />
        </div>
    </td>
    if (i % 3 == 2 || i == Model.Clients.Count - 1)
    {
        </tr>
    }
}
```