# 3 records per row (<tr>) using modulos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a collection of 12 items, I would like to put them in a table but I would like to have 3 records per row (3 columns) on each `tr`.

I am having difficulties with what the proper expression for the % symbol is.
I have this so far.

```
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Amenities.Count; i++)
    {
        var amenity = Model.Amenities[i];
        if ((i % 3) == 0)
        {
            @:<tr>
        }
                <td>@amenity.Description</td>
        if ((i % 3) == 0 && i>0)
        {
            @:</tr>
        }

    }
</table>
```

**UPDATE**
I solved the row issue by doing the following for those that want to use a paged system. **However**, Andrew's answer using bootstraps built in new-line thing was a much better answer and I will be using it. for more info here is the link [Display three columns per row in MVC cshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150361/display-three-columns-per-row-in-mvc-cshtml)

```
    @{
    int pageSize = 3;
    var totalPages = Model.Amenities.Count / pageSize;
    if (Model.Amenities.Count % pageSize != 0)
    {
        totalPages++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < totalPages; i++)
    {
        var currentPage = Model.Amenities.Skip(i * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        <div class="row">
            @foreach (var amenity in currentPage)
            {
                <div class="col-md-4">

                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="@amenity.AmenityID">@amenity.Description
                    </label>
                </div>

            }
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Map/expose the data into a two dimensional structure in the model instead, rather than trying to embed this logic into the view.

Comment: sounds like a good idea.. will just page the 12 records into 4 pages (collections) using .Skip

Comment: Maping this into a two dimensional structure in the model (view model) may or may not be a good idea. That depends on your requirements. If you may want to change the number of columns to 4 in the future for example, then it's better not to make the structure in your model, so you can make the change just by changing the view. Check my answer below.

Comment: I just answered a question very similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150361/display-three-columns-per-row-in-mvc-cshtml.

Comment: @AndrewCounts perfect answer as bootstrap already provides this, I will be using your suggestion.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general solution that will work for any given number of columns and any number of items:

```
<table>
    @{
        int numOfCols = 3; // You can change the number of columns here
        int numOfRows = Math.Ceiling(Model.Amenities.Count / numOfCols);
        // or if you don't want to use Math.Ceiling...
        // int numOfRows = Model.Amenities.Count / numOfCols;
        // if (Model.Amenities.Count % numOfCols != 0)
        //     numOfRows++;
    }
    @for (int row = 0; row < numOfRows; row++)
    {
        <tr>
            for (int col = 0; col < numOfCols; col++)
            {
                int index = row * numOfCols + col;
                if(index < Model.Amenities.Count)
                {
                    var amenity = Model.Amenities[index];
                    <td>@amenity.Description</td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

By the way, you can pass the number of columns from your Controller in a `ViewBag` item. Also, you can incorporate this into an `HtmlHelper` that gets the number of columns and an `IEnumerable` model, and renders this table.

Comment: Your code will throw an index out of bounds error if the total number of items isn't evenly divisible by the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Batch method of MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28).  It will allow you to batch the data into groups of up to 3 items:

```
<table>
    @foreach(var row in Model.Amenities.Batch(3))
    {
        @:<tr>
        @foreach (var amenity in row)
        {
            <td>@amenity.Description</td>
        }
        @:</tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: I want to use the morelinq library but the .Batch method doesnt seem to be available on the view. even included the @using morelinq namespace. however in code behind its available, just not in razor.  Am i missing something?

Comment: @Zoinky I'm not familiar enough with Razor to tell you what the problem is.  You could simply create an additional read-only property on your model however that returns the amenities batched, and then use that from the view.