# displaying 3 columns in a row when layout is null in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

[Display three columns per row in MVC cshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150361/display-three-columns-per-row-in-mvc-cshtml)

```
<div class="row">
<div id="dataListItem" class="col-md-4">
    @Html.Hidden("ClientID", ClientItem.ClientID)
    @Html.Label(ClientItem.ClientName)
    <input type='checkbox' name="ClientItemCheckBox" 
                id="ClientItemCheckBox" style="color: #428bca;" />
</div>
```

USING ABOVE code
it works perfect when layout of cshtml page is not null
but when layout is null all the data is placed one below another in vertical manner

Comment: Include the bootstrap css file in your view.

Answer (score 0):

solution to your problem is simple.

you got the output when the layout is not null , that because it uses the bootstrap.css files which is having all the css related code:

[Example Bootstrap grid](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp)

But if you want layout should be null for some requirement, you can still get the bootstrap reference in view files itself by using the following code:

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Hope it was helpful.

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: Hi Surekha ,if it was really helpful to resolve your problem ,Accept it, so that others also will make use of it.Happy sharing..:) Thanks karthik